# Identify The Masters

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, merchandise

I got this T-Shirt a while back, as a gift. It is, of course, an hommage to the famous Beatles album, but with iconic masters. But, being the nerd I am, I am slightly embarrassed to admit that I only recognize half of the characters depicted:

[image: four cartoonist characters on a crosswalk, Beatles-like pose]

From left to right:

1. [Muten Roshi](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Master_Roshi), from *Dragon Ball*
2. [Yoda,](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yoda) from *Star Wars*
3. ?
4. ?

Who are the other two Masters?

Comment: the real question is... "WHERE DID THEY GET THIS SHIRT?!?!?"

Comment: @JimGreen Well, I could ask the person who gave it to me. But if you google for "t-shirt the masters", you can find many different versions of it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The third one is [Master Dohko](https://saintseiya.fandom.com/wiki/Libra_D%C5%8Dko) from *Saint Seiya*.

The fourth one is the Dungeon Master from the 80's D&D cartoon:

Comment: Those are some oddly niche references

Comment: Amongst my peers (age 40ish and live in UK) Dungeons and Dragons is well remembered, and fondly so.

Comment: Could you add in the first two characters as well?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage why? They're already in the question?